# Python regex negative lookbehind matching confusion

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match source  when time is between 12 PM - 4 PM.

st = "error 1/23/2020 11:53:41 PM Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM 10010 None The server {4AA0A5C4-1B9B-4F2E-99D7-99C6AEC83474} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout."

```
".+/2020 (?<=12:\d\d:\d\d PM)|(?<=[1-3]:\d\d:\d\d PM) (.+?) \d+"
```

Why is the above regex capturing Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM given that time is 11:53:41 PM. Isn't it suppose to ignore it ?

Comment: `"1:53:41"` is a part of `"11:53:41"`, and you don't check that there's a space before it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your pattern is that `(?<=[1-3]:\d\d:\d\\d PM)` can actually assert on the *second* digit in `11:53:41`, and satisfy the assertion that way.  I suggest using `re.findall` here and doing away with the lookbehind, which are clumsy and error prone.

```py
st = "error 1/23/2020 11:53:41 PM Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM 10010 None The server {4AA0A5C4-1B9B-4F2E-99D7-99C6AEC83474} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout."
matches = re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/2020 (?:[1-3]|12):\d{2}:\d{2} PM (.+?)\d+', st)
print(matches)  # []
```

Note that if the timestamp were `1/23/2020 12:53:41 PM`, then the match would be `Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM`.